# How do i add an attribute in an existing json file using java

Tags: java

I need to add a resource type attribute which takes dynamic value in the json file which i already have in my system .

I have tried writing the code but it's not working

This is the json i have (i have only shared first few lines)

```
{
  "id": "example",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
```

And my required output after writing the code is

```
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "id": "example",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
```

The resourceType field gets added and the value of the attribute we get is according to the requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectMapper` to deserialise it in POJO, set the attribute and deserialise it back to String, e.g.:

```
class Example {
    private String id;
    private String resourceType;
    private Text text;

    //getters and setters

}

class Text {

    private String status;

    //getters and setters
}

public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception { 
    String string = "{\n" + 
            "  \"id\": \"example\",\n" + 
            "  \"text\": {\n" + 
            "    \"status\": \"generated\""
            + "} "
            + "}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Example example = objectMapper.readValue(string, Example.class);
    example.setResourceType("Patient");
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(example));
}
```

[Here's](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) the documentation for Jackson.